# How to update subprojects in Cocos2d-x project

Tags: cmake, cocos2d-x

I've just started playing with Cocos2d-x v3.8.1 and I have a problem how to update subprojects.

```
cocos new SampleProject -p com.domain.sampleproject -l cpp -d .
```

For above command `cocos`:

- creates two sample classes: `AppDelegate` and `HelloWorldScene`,
- creates subprojects: `proj.android`, `proj.android-studio`,
  `proj.linux`, `proj.win32`, `proj.ios_mac`, `proj.win10`, `proj.win8.1-universal`,
- creates `CMakeLists.txt`.

In regular project after `cocos new` we need to add new source files.
After the addition of new files, sub-projects are outdated.
The question is **how to update those sub-projects**?

I know that I can edit `CMakeLists.txt` and call e.g. `cmake . -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"`, but that gives me files that doesn't keep the structure convention.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I lived this problem when I abandoned (temporary) my private project. I believe that it is possible to solve using CMake.